# How to install Ubuntu on my second partition

Tags: installation

I am currently using a Toshiba Portege and have installed Window 7 on the first partition (C:drive) allocating 200GB for it. On the second partition (D:drive) I have allocated 100GB and wish to install Ubuntu Desktop 12.10 on it. I am a novice and I would really appreciate if someone could help me do this. Please reply

Answer (score 1):

You can download the iso image of ubuntu 12.10 then get it on a CD or Flash disk. When booting on the previously created CD or flash, follow the instructions and when you get the partitions screen create a swap partition with 2 or 3 Gb and you ubuntu partition "/". That's all. See it's easy :)

Comment: Hi Hakeem but how do I create the swap partition and the Ubuntu partition? Pliz reply.

Comment: in the disk manager create a 2 or 3 Gb partition and select the "swap" type when selecting the system files ( not ext2, ext3 or ext4)

Comment: Hi Hakeem, I've done what you said and I'm now using Ubuntu. I'm sending you this reply using Ubuntu OS. Have logged in to Windows too to check and no problem at all. Thanks a lot for your help. Best regards.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer, now that your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download the ubuntu ISO from the website http://www.ubuntu.com/download
then burn it to a disk as a disk image.  Then put it into your CD drive and restart your computer.  When ubuntu screen comes up you will have to go through the insrtuctions when it comes to the part about the hard drive choose the 100 gigabyte drive and countinue with the instruction. 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest

Comment: Hi Wil. Sorry I should have added some more information on my first post. The thing is I've done all that you explained above and I have the USB here with me. I tried to install it but it says that I need to create a swap folder. How do I do that? My laptop has a 2GB RAM.